# Convert a list column to single observations in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, reshape

I have a dataframe with a column where each row is a list. Like this:

```
> df
 
recipe_id     ingredients      

        1     c("cheese", "milk")
        2     c("egg", "chocolate") 
        3     c("rice", "corn")
```

And I want to turn it into:

```
> df
 
recipe_id     ingredients      

        1     cheese
        1     milk
        2     egg
        2     chocolate
        3     rice
        3     corn
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `unnest` in `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
unnest(df, ingredients)
```

#### data

```
df <- tibble(recipe_id = 1:3, 
   ingredients = list( c("cheese", "milk"), 
        c("egg", "chocolate") ,  c("rice", "corn")))
```